# Changed SVN Repo in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn

I was refactoring my code which lays in a SVN repository and both added new files aswell as changed existing files. I also renamed/moved some existing files in different directories. Now since I am using a SVN Plugin in Eclipse I thought the plugin could manage that. Unfortunately right now I can't commit and I don't want to setup the repository completely new since this would mean I would loose the whole history.

This is what I get as an error:

```
Some of selected resources were not added to version control. (multiple times)
Some of selected resources were not committed.

svn: E150002: 'C:\somePath' is already under version control
(multiple times)

svn: E200009: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E200009: 'C:\path' is not under version control
```

When I try to commit via Tortoise SVN this is what I get:

```
 Commit failed (details follow):
Cannot commit 'C:\path'
 because it was moved to
 'C:\otherPath'
 which is not part of the commit; both sides of the move must be committed
 together
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I also renamed/moved some existing files in different directories.
>
> ...............................
>
> When I try to commit via Tortoise SVN this is what I get:
>
> which is not part of the commit; both sides of the move must be committed
> together

When moving/renaming files, you must commit parent folder which contains both old and new path.

Comment: Yeah i figured it out by myself. Looks like there was more corrupted than I thought but your answer targets the question I asked which is why I mark you as accepted.